# Linker - Data constants replaced by garbage

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, cortex-m

I'm trying to integrate some third-party library to my project.
I compile all my files with no problems, but when i try to add custom library, all constants in this library becomes garbage.

Here is my linker command (split over lines for readability):

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc 
-Wall 
-Wextra 
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable 
-mthumb 
-mfloat-abi=soft 
-mcpu=cortex-m4 
-ffunction-sections 
-fdata-sections 
-ffreestanding 
-g -ggdb -gdwarf-2 -g3 
-Ibuild/ -Iinc/ -ICMSIS/ -I../lib/ -I.
-fverbose-asm
-DSTM32F407xx
-Wl,--gc-sections
-Wl,-Map=build/output.map
--specs=nosys.specs
-TLinkerScript.ld
-o build/main.elf
build/main.o {tons of o-files} ../lib/sdk.a
```

Here is the objdump for one function, first in library and then in resulting ELF:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -S ../lib/sdk.a build/main.elf | grep "<some_function>:" -A 9

00000000 <some_function>:
   0:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (c <some_function+0xc>)
   2:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <some_function+0x10>)
   4:   447b        add r3, pc
   6:   589b        ldr r3, [r3, r2]
   8:   6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
   a:   4770        bx  lr
   c:   00000004    .word   0x00000004
  10:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

08004b28 <some_function>:
 8004b28:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (8004b34 <some_function+0xc>)
 8004b2a:   4a03        ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; (8004b38 <some_function+0x10>)
 8004b2c:   447b        add r3, pc
 8004b2e:   589b        ldr r3, [r3, r2]
 8004b30:   6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
 8004b32:   4770        bx  lr
 8004b34:   17ffc880    .word   0x17ffc880
 8004b38:   00000164    .word   0x00000164
```

Notice:
`.word  0x00000004`
replaced by
`.word  0x17ffc880`

What can cause such transformation an how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x00000004` in library is not a real value - it's just an offset which needs to be added to some external symbol. The name of the symbol is stored in so called relocation section and can be displayed by running `objdump -Sr`.

The value of the external symbol is unknown until link-time but once the code is fully linked, the offset is replaced with final (so called "absolute") address which happens to be `0x17ffc880` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `0x17ffc880` is non-existent address and `r3` is size that is being sent to malloc. Obviously, there is no such space available and i get UsageFault

Comment: @NevaDA Interesting. Could you add `-dS` output to your question? This might give a cluen.

Comment: `-Sr` in fact, gave me a clue.
You are correct - this code is, in fact, made for relocation. It is fo-called PIC (position-independent code).

I've located a problem - compiler did not include `.got` section, neither this section was loaded b startup script.